# Pull and run docker image from docker hub using Concourse pipeline

Tags: pipeline, concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-fly, concourse-resource-types

I have pushed the image to docker hub and now trying to pull the docker image from docker hub into Ec2 instance and run that image using CONCCOURSE.

Image is pushed to docker hub.
Unable to pull image from docker hub using concourse
Unable to run the pulled image using concourse